# How to use a variable as criteria for the sumifs formula in vba

Tags: vba, excel, formulas, sumifs

Can anybody please help me with the correction of the following code:

```
Dim Medium As String

Medium = "XYZ"

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(List2!C[8],List2!C[2],""=XYZ"",List2!C[11],""=prime"")"
```

I need to replace the `""=XYZ""` part of the code with the variable

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
Dim Medium As String    
Medium = "XYZ"    
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(List2!C[8],List2!C[2]," & _
                         Chr(34) & _
                         Medium & _
                         Chr(34) & _
                         ",List2!C[11],""=prime"")"
```

Comment: Indeed, perfection is simplicity))))

Comment: If you're happy with the solution proposed - please accept the answer by ticking it, this will mark the question solved. For the details see: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/210367)